# Setting the Route for a Form in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel, and I want to set a form, I have the following in my view.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('date_process') }}">
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', 'DateFormController@show');
Route::post('/date_process', 'DateFormController@process');
```

I get the following error message.

> Route [date_process] not defined.

How can I have set the form action to send to `date_process`?

Comment: It might be easier to use Resource routes, that way you don't need to make several routes for your basic CRUD routines - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers

Comment: You need to name your route to use `route("date_process")`, like `->name("date_process")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `route` helper function will output named routes. Your route is unnamed. You can either add a name to the route or use the `url` helper instead.

```
Route::post('/date_process', 'DateFormController@process')->name('date_process');

route('date_process')
```

or with your current route

```
url('date_process')
```

Comment: I named the route but I getting "419,Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again. " message

Comment: @afd25 That means the route is being output correctly, but your form is missing the CSRF token. inside the form add `@csrf` (assuming you're using blade).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('date_process') }}">
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
</body>
@csrf

</html>

Route::get('/', 'DateFormController@show');
Route::post('/date_process', 'DateFormController@process')->name('date_process');

or
Route::get('/', 'DateFormController@show');
Route::post('/date_process', ['uses'=>'DateFormController@process','as'=>'date_process']);
```